# Submit process from Plugin parameter screen once when the parameters are saved

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7

I want to process a script whenever a plugin parameter is changed and the save button is clicked in Joomla. I do not want to run it everytime, but as soon the save button is pressed, the script should execute and then should lie dormant until it is invoked again

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use either of these events (from `com_plugins/models/plugin.php` )

```
/**
 * @var     string  The event to trigger after saving the data.
 * @since   1.6
 */
protected $event_after_save = 'onExtensionAfterSave';

/**
 * @var     string  The event to trigger after before the data.
 * @since   1.6
 */
protected $event_before_save = 'onExtensionBeforeSave';
```

If you look at the base/core plugins installed with Joomla! in `/plugins/` you can find examples of these and other triggers being used.

Comment: Hi Cppl, Could you please give an example on this as I am unable to see an implementation of this on web

Comment: Look in the `/plugins/folder/` at the default/core plugins you see examples of both of these triggers.